# Unable to get arrow function to work

Tags: material-ui, babeljs, arrow-functions

I am trying to upgrade to es6 for an existing project with Babel. My package.json contains the babel plugins:

````
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.8.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "^2.9.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.15.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.5.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"

My .babelrc file the following:

    {
      "presets": ["es2015", "stage-1", "react"],
      "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
        "transform-class-properties"
        ]

    }

And my webpack file contains the following:

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-2']
    },
    {
     test: /\.scss$/,
     loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
    }
  ]}
```
````

And I run my node app with the following command:

```
cp views/index.html public/index.html && NODE_ENV=development webpack && npm run webpack-dev-server"
```

I am using a toggle function with material-ui in order to get `Drawer` component triggered by a hamburger menu in the Appbar component.

The Toggle functions are as follows (as per [documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer))

````
```
  handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

  handleClose = () => this.setState({open: false});
``
````

However, whenever I run this I get the following error:

```
Unexpected token (29:16)
  27 | 
  28 | 
> 29 | handleToggle () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
     |                 ^
  30 |
```

If I change the function from arrow to a more old-school approach I can get it to work i.e.

```
  handleToggle() {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
    alert("handleToggle clicked");
   }
```

However, I do not want to have to customise every component in material-ui in order to enable it to be backwards compatible. How do I upgrade my code without getting errors?

Comment: You might show in your package file, how you are starting your app. I'm thinking you're not actually transpiling your code.

Comment: Could you clarify? Do I need to install a transpiller? Or does webpack and bundle.js do the job? `module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  //bundle app from here
  entry: './app-client.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/dist',
    //output it to /public/dist/bundle.js
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  devServer: {
    // This is required for webpack-dev-server. The path should
    // be an absolute path to your build destination.
    outputPath: path.join(__dirname +  '/public/')
}`

Comment: Babel is the transpiler. What do you run on the command line to execute your node app? I don't think you ever run the code through Babel.

Comment: `npm run development`, I also tried `webpack-dev-server ` just now. Same result.

Comment: And what is in package.json for the development script?

Comment: `"development": "cp views/index.html public/index.html && NODE_ENV=development webpack && npm run webpack-dev-server"`